# How to write a new dictionary object to plist containing an array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, plist

I'm new to Objective-C programming and I'm trying to write a new dictionary object to a plist containing an array of dictionaries with the intent of persisting the data.

My plist structure is:

```
<plist>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>toyName</key>
            <string>N64</string>
            <key>toyBrand</key>
            <string>Nintendo</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

Function where I try write new dictionary:

```
-(void)saveData {
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager new];
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSURL *docsurl = [fm URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                            inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                   appropriateForURL:nil
                              create:YES
                               error:&err];
    NSURL *url = [docsurl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Toy.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *plistData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    NSDate * now = [NSDate date];

    [newDict setValue:itemText.text forKey:@"toyName"];
    [newDict setValue:brandText.text forKey:@"toyBrand"];

    [plistData addObject:newDict];
}
```

When the saveData function is called, the plistData array is still the same when I print using NSLog, and the plist has not changed. How to do I write a new dictionary object to a plist containing an array of dictionaries?

Comment: Where did you print your `plistData` with `NSLog`?

Comment: @RyanB I printed it directly below NSMutableArray *plistData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];

Comment: What did not change? The plist keeps showing `nil` or its list not getting updated with `newDict`?

Comment: Debug your code, step over it line by line, you should be able to identify the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

There is code to add `[plistData writeToURL:url atomically:YES]` below `[plistData addObject:newDict]`, but you must make sure that plistData is not nil,hat is, to find the corresponding file through the url.

For example:

```
-(void)saveData {
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager new];
        NSError *err = nil;
        NSURL *docsurl = [fm URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                       appropriateForURL:nil
                                  create:YES
                                   error:&err];
        NSURL *url = [docsurl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Toy.plist"];

        NSMutableArray *plistData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        NSDate * now = [NSDate date];

        [newDict setValue:itemText.text forKey:@"toyName"];
        [newDict setValue:brandText.text forKey:@"toyBrand"];

        [plistData addObject:newDict];
    }
```